# Read each line from a file and proceed to take the log of the values to use in a fitting function

Tags: python, loops, numpy, scipy

I have a list of values, say

```
13, 21, 33
24, 43, 80 and so on.
```

I am trying to read each line individually, and then take the log of each line
So for ex.

```
logy = log10(13, 21, 33)
```

In a loop, going through each line individually.

I then use the log values as an y value to a power law fit. Then I get the index for the fit of each line.

I am however unable to do read the lines and take their log individually with a loop. Any suggestions as to how I can do this? The number of lines I have is small.

So far I have-

```
from numpy import log10
from scipy import optimize
from math import sqrt

x = [3.6, 4.5, 5.8, 8.0]
y809   =1.390275E-12,6.859800000000001E-13,3.901267241379311E-13,1.55844E-13
yy816   =2.4975E-12,1.2187800000000002E-12,6.510724137931035E-13,2.55119625E-13
logx = log10(x)


logy = log10(y809)
logyerr = 0.05

fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0] + p[1] * x
errfunc = lambda p, x, y, err: (y - fitfunc(p, x)) / err

pinit = [1.0, -1.0]
out = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, pinit,
                       args=(logx, logy, logyerr), full_output=1)

pfinal = out[0]
covar = out[1]
print pfinal
print covar

index = pfinal[1]
amp = 10.0**pfinal[0]

indexErr = sqrt( covar[0][0] )
ampErr = sqrt( covar[1][1] ) * amp
```

As you can see I haven't figured out how to read and take the log of each line.

Comment: could you please show us your code?

Comment: I don't understand how you can have more than 1 argument to log10 ?

Comment: firstly, sorry, I didn't paste the whole copy of my code, I have done now-x = [3.6, 4.5, 5.8, 8.0] y809 =13, 14, 15, 20 and so on y values logx = log10(x) logy = log10(y809) logyerr = 0.05 fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0] + p[1] * x errfunc = lambda p, x, y, err: (y - fitfunc(p, x)) / err pinit = [1.0, -1.0] out = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, pinit, args=(logx, logy, logyerr), full_output=1) pfinal = out[0] covar = out[1] print pfinal print covar index = pfinal[1] amp = 10.0**pfinal[0] indexErr = sqrt( covar[0][0] ) ampErr = sqrt( covar[1][1] ) * amp

Comment: I think formatting this in your question would be way more readable, thanks!

Comment: Hi Frodon, I assume the value of each argument is taken the log of separately. For example, I tried y = 10,1,0, and logy = log10(y) I get the right answer i.e. 1, 0, inf.

Comment: So what part of my answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: @user2398849: ok I understand now that you use numpy and scipy

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
with open('data.txt','r') as f:                     #<-- open file
    next(f)                                         #<-- skip header
    for line in f:                                  #<-- read line by line
        args = [float(x) for x in line.split(' ')]  #<-- parse line into list
        print log10(args)                           #<-- run log10 on list
```

Comment: This gives the following exception: `TypeError: a float is required` (edit: I suppose log10 comes from the `math` module)

Comment: I'm not sure either.  numpy has a `log10` which takes in an iterable.

Comment: Hi jh314, I think I'm making a mistake in reading in the line as a string as I get the following error-invalid literal for int() with base 10:''2.78055E-12            1.68498E-12            9.456051724137932E-13  5.3946E-13            \n' I've never read data using text files before so Im unsure?

Comment: What does the first 2 lines of your file look like?

Comment: Replace int() by float() ?

Comment: And are the numbers comma separated, or space separated?

Comment: # F36                    F45`                   F58                    F8                    
   2.78055E-12            1.68498E-12            9.456051724137932E-13  5.3946E-13            
  9.740249999999999E-12  5.241420000000001E-12  2.707634482758621E-12  1.14260625E-12 That is the first two lines and the header. I've tried both .csv and .dat formats

Comment: Okay, this should work now (if your file has 1 header, and your numbers are floats and separated by spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is in comma delimited file, `data.txt`

```
import numpy as np
a=np.genfromtxt('data.txt',delimiter=',')
[np.log10(x) for x in [a[y,:] for y in range(len(a))]]
```

gives the log of each value, with a separate array for each line:

```
[array([ 1.11394335,  1.32221929,  1.51851394]), array([ 1.38021124,  1.63346846,  1.90308999])]
```